# Scheduled notifications in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-local-notification

I'm writing an food app, which I want it to send notification when some product is about to expire. I have used flutter_local_notification plugin and managed to create a method for schedule notification 7 days before picked date from datepicker. In my scaffold , when I'm adding one new product to my list, the notification is working fine. But when I add one product after the other, notification appears only for the second one. It looks like after adding new product to list, instead of creating new notification, it looks like the old one is overwritten.

I have used UniqueKey().hashcode for unique notification id. Here I'm putting my method and my adding page.

```
Future<void> scheduleNotification(DateTime expDate, BuildContext context,
      String? title, int notificationId) async {
    final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
        FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    var scheduleNotificationDateTime = expDate.subtract(
      const Duration(days: 7),
    );
    AndroidNotificationDetails androidDetails =
        const AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'channel 1',
      'candys',
      'channel.discription',
      importance: Importance.high,
      priority: Priority.max,
      icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
      playSound: true,
    );
    NotificationDetails notificationDetails =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidDetails);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.schedule(
      notificationId,
      'Przypomnienie w ${AppLocalizations.of(context)!.candys}',
      'Kończy się data ważności produktu $title',
      scheduleNotificationDateTime,
      notificationDetails,
      androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
      
    );
  }

class CandyAddPage extends StatefulWidget {
  CandyAddPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  @override
  State<CandyAddPage> createState() => _CandyAddPageState();
}

class _CandyAddPageState extends State<CandyAddPage> {
  String? _title;
  DateTime? _expDate;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) =>
          CandyPageCubit(CandyDocumentsRepository(CandyRemoteDataSource())),
      child: BlocBuilder<CandyPageCubit, CandyPageState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          final notificationId = context.read<int>();
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 51, 54),
              title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.addProduct),
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: _title == null || _expDate == null
                      ? null
                      : () {
                          context
                              .read<CandyPageCubit>()
                              .add(_title!, _expDate!);
                          context.read<CandyPageCubit>().scheduleNotification(
                              _expDate!, context, _title, notificationId);
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.check),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            body: _AddPageBody(
              onTitleChanged: (newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  _title = newValue;
                });
              },
              onDateChanged: (newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  _expDate = newValue;
                });
              },
              selectedDateFormated: _expDate == null
                  ? null
                  : DateFormat.yMMMd().format(_expDate!),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any suggestions will be helpful.
Thanks!

Comment: try updating your `flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin` to v10 + to access `flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(`

Comment: You can just generate a six digit number and use it as your notification ID. Just save it in your local database so you can unschedule it by the ID later. 


int generateRandomId() {
   final rnd = Random();
   return rnd.nextInt(900000) + 100000;
}

Comment: I will try this six digit random number, but I thought UniqueKey generates unique value so when I create another notification, it will have its own id. But maybe it' also associated with channel id or channel name?

Answer (score 0):

Update:

So I tried to print value of notificationId in debug console and I realised that every time I press button, instead of new random number, the same value is showing. I found out that, when I exit and reopen page with `final notificationId = UniqueKey().hashCode;` , new value is generating, which works as needed. Because of this my question is why do I need to reopen page to generate new id?

Here I'm putting my code where unique id is generating.

```
class CandyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const CandyPage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final notificationId = UniqueKey().hashCode;
    return Provider<int>(
      create: (context) => notificationId,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: const CandyPageAppBar(),
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 250, 252, 250),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 51, 54),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Provider<int>(
                    create: (context) => notificationId, child: CandyAddPage()),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: const Icon(
            Icons.add,
          ),
        ),
        body: const CandyPageBody(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```